# Example users list for import into Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, import, csv

I am in the process of learning a Microsoft course AD DS for Windows Server 2008.
To practice, I need at least 1000 users to import into my server, so **I wonder if there is an example .csv list to download with fictional users to import them into my server**.

It is really a waste of time to add users one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a simple batch file.

`FOR /L %%i in (1,1,5000) DO NET USER Joe%%i HugeComplexPassWord%%i /ADD`

Then use csvde to export it. . .